# ROS pcl run-time error segmenting planes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am trying to write a program that subscribes to the openni_launch's pointcloud topic, downsamples the data, and publishes an extracted pointcloud plane. So far the code compiles fine but upon running it produces this error:

/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr::reference boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void >, boost::shared_ptr::reference = sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_std::allocator<void >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

I am unsure of where the error is coming from and would appreciate any insight. Here is the code I have written thus far:

```
   // Includes and whatnot

    ros::Publisher pub;
    sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::Ptr downsampled,output;
    
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr output_p, downsampled_XYZ;
    
    
    void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& input)
    {
      // Do some downsampling to the point cloud
      pcl::VoxelGrid<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> sor;
      sor.setInputCloud (input);
      sor.setLeafSize (0.01f, 0.01f, 0.01f);
      sor.filter (*downsampled);
    
      // Change from type sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 to pcl::PointXYZ
      pcl::fromROSMsg (*downsampled, *downsampled_XYZ);
    
    
      pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients ());
      pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices ());
      // Create the segmentation object
      pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
      // Optional
      seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
      // Mandatory
      seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_PLANE);
      seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
      seg.setMaxIterations (1000);
      seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);
    
      // Create the filtering object
      pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZ> extract;
    
      // Segment the largest planar component from the cloud
      seg.setInputCloud (downsampled_XYZ);
      seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
      if (inliers->indices.size () == 0)
          {
              std::cerr << "Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset." << std::endl;
              }
    
      // Extract the inliers
      extract.setInputCloud (downsampled_XYZ);
      extract.setIndices (inliers);
      extract.setNegative (false);
      extract.filter (*output_p);
      std::cerr << "PointCloud representing the planar component: " << output_p->width * output_p->height << " data points." << std::endl;
    
      // Create the filtering object
      // extract.setNegative (true);
      // extract.filter (*cloud_f);
      // cloud_filtered.swap (cloud_f);
    
    
      pcl::toROSMsg (*output_p, *output);
    
      //Publish the results
      pub.publish(output);
    }
    
    
    
    
    int
    main (int argc, char** argv)
    {
     // INITIALIZE ROS
      ros::init (argc, argv, "table");
      ros::NodeHandle nh;
      ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("/camera/depth_registered/points", 1, callback);
      
      pub = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> ("table", 1);
    
      ros::spin();
    
    
      return (0);
    }
```

Thank you in advance!

Cheers,
Martin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39818/ros-pcl-run-time-error-segmenting-planes/) by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 464 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-07-25**:
Found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541179/shared-ptr-assertion-px-0-failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am guessing that you should allocate the memory for *output_p* and *downsampled_XYZ* when you enter the callback.

Also, one more advice, after

```
pcl::toROSMsg (*output_p, *output);
```

You should set the *frame_id* of *output* to the same value as *input*

```
output.header.frame_id = input->header.frame_id;
```

otherwise if you try to visualize the point cloud with *rviz*, it will complain because it would not know the frame of reference for *output*.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MartinW](https://answers.ros.org/users/2868/martinw/) on 2012-07-26**:
Thanks! I got my program running and I've extracted the pointcloud plane of a table in front of my Kinect! I tried to add your line of code "output.header.frame_id = input->header.frame_id;"
But when I did it said sensor_msgs::pointcloud2 has no member header. But I could see it in Rviz anyway!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ::Ptr output_p(new pcl::PointCloudpcl::PointXYZ);

That did it for me :)

---

Originally posted by [sharky](https://answers.ros.org/users/6244/sharky/) with karma: 36 on 2013-12-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2